# 連続変数からのダミー変数作成

Tags: python, pandas

連続的な変数から、0－1のダミー変数を作成する場合を考えています。
今、マンションの階数を示す変数がkaiに入っています。
この変数から、１階の場合には、1、それ以外は0とするダミー変数 floor_1 を作成したい
と考えています。

現在は、for文とif文の組合わせで作成しているのですが、
うまくできたり、できなかったりします。

下記の場合ですと、エラーが出ています。
よりスマートな方法があれば、ご教示頂けますとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'kai': ['2', '-1', '1', '20']},
    index=[1, 2, 3,4])


# 1階ダミー
floor_1_ser = np.zeros((len(df),1))
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['kai'][i] == 1:
        floor_1_ser[i] = 1

df["floor_1"] = floor_1_ser

df['floor_1'].describe() 
del(floor_1_ser)
```

Comment: `if df['kai'][i] == 1:`の行は`if df['kai'][i + 1] ==  '1':`ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 有用なご指摘を頂き、ありがとうございます。検討致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず

```
df.kai == '1'
```

の結果が

```
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: kai, dtype: bool
```

になります。
ここからnumpyのarrayを生成すると、

```
np.array(df.kai == '1')
# => array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

ですね。

ところで、Pythonのbool型は実は[数値型](http://docs.python.jp/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) (順序型)なので、intに変換するとFalseは0、Trueは1になります。

```
int(True)
# => 1
int(False)
# => 0
```

したがって、型を数値型にすると、

```
np.array(df.kai == '1', dtype=int)
# => array([0, 0, 1, 0])
```

が得られます。（必要なら浮動小数点にしてください）

あとは次元を操作して、

```
np.array(df.kai == '1', dtype=int)[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0]])
```

とすればよさそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試してみます。まずは、取り急ぎの御礼まで。

Comment: 次のコマンドでうまく動きました。ありがとうございました。df["floor_1"] = np.array(df.kai == '1', dtype=int)[:, np.newaxis]